# Android layout weight doesn't do anything

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have a LinearLayout with 2 buttons splitting it horizontally.

I want those buttons to be at the bottom of the screen, so I added to the layout
`android:layout_weight="bottom"` and nothing changes!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Stop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: BTW: You don't need a `weight_sum` if the nested views take up the entire space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `layout_width` of your buttons to `0dp`.

Additionally there is no width property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Stop" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I changed it the buttons' width to 0dp, and yeah I dont know why I put the width property.. and it still doesn't change anything..

Comment: You are using the wrong attribute for the parent layout. It should be android:gravity="bottom" if you want the child object to sit at the bottom of its parent container (in this case the linearlayout), you have used layout_gravity, which is a child attribute.

Comment: The linear layout is a child of the main linear layout . I want the whole (child)layout to be at the bottom

Comment: Your original code does not show a child linear layout. You have a single parent layout with two buttons, where is the other layout? If this is not your complete layout please update your post with the full layout file.

Comment: I'm glad this resolved your issue, please mark it as the answer so it can help others :)

Comment: I did, and, is there a solution with linear layout? because when I used it in another layout, there are new problems of relative layouts like one element overlapping another..

Comment: If you want to dock elements you cannot use LinearLayout, you need to use RelativeLayout. In addition if you want to evenly space elements you need to use LinearLayout because it has the layout_weight property which inversely RelativeLayout does not have. You could get so far just using LinearLayout and mix of margin properties etc but you would never guarantee your elements would sit at the bottom of the screen for all devices. Hence you use the approach above.

Answer (score 1):

The layout_weight is used to divide up remaining space *after* layout_width or layout_height have been taken into account.

When you say

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Start"
    android:width="0dp" />
```

The `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` says to set the size of the button to as wide as its parent. Doing so for two buttons in a horizontal linear layout will result in only one visible button; the second is actually positioned to the right of the first, but offscreen.

If you set the `layout_width` to `0dp` for both buttons, both buttons will have the same width.

If you set the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` on both buttons, both will start at their "preferred" width and then have additional space allocated to them based on the ratio of their `layout_width` to the sum of the `layout_width`s of all views in the parent layout.

If you want the buttons at the bottom, you can either change your layout to a relative layout (and use `alignParentBottom` as mentioned in other answers), or nest inside a vertical linear layout (the horizontal layout would have `layout_height='wrap_content'` and `layout_width='fill_parent'`).

Because you mentioned nesting, you could use something like

```
<LinearLayout
    andrdoid:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ...
    >
        <LinearLayout
            anddoid:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...
            >
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    ... />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    ... />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

(or use `wrap_content` for the `layout_width` of the buttons to start them at their text widths)

Answer (score 0):

change the layout_width param on the buttons to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Also you can use layout_alignParentBottom

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

You can create your layout file like following

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <!-- Other Components of your layout file -->
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Start"/>

    <Button
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Stop"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" with a linearLayout, this is a property of a RelativeLayout

Comment: it still doesn't work, and it warns me about layout_alignParentBottom

Answer (score 0):

Your title says layout_weight isn't working for you, but the question body implies it is working just fine. The `layout_weight` attribute should be causing your buttons to take up half the width each.

The positioning at the bottom of the screen is a different issue. Based on your recently edited xml, add `android:gravity="bottom"` to the parent `LinearLayout`, or `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the child `LinearLayout`.